# cachefilesd vs NIS automounter

Tags: nfs, autofs, nis

I want to cache NFS mounts

My NFS mounts are handled by the automounter which is governed by NIS

I need to add the mount option, fsc, to the mounts to enable the cache

=> Where do I add this option?

auto.master is essentially empty because NIS is supplying all the mapping - I cannot see where I can set any mount options!

Users log in, through some hidden magic of NIS and the automount their homes are mounted but I simply can't find where I'd turn the caching on.